# Lockscreen background change first time and never again

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

The app generate an image from a `UserControl` into IsoStorage:

```
var bitmap6 = new WriteableBitmap(336, 336);
bitmap6.Render(LockscreenBG, new TranslateTransform());
var stream6 = store.CreateFile("/shared/shellcontent/LockscreenBG.jpg");
bitmap6.Invalidate();
bitmap6.SaveJpeg(stream6, 336, 336, 0, 100);
stream6.Close();
```

within a common Class Library - which is used by the app and the background agent - is this:

```
if (LockScreenManager.IsProvidedByCurrentApplication)
{
  LockScreen.SetImageUri(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/shared/shellcontent/LockscreenBG.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

Everything works very well but only the first time. The image still is the same without any errors. Seems like the image is not overwritten or it is used the old one from the cache???

Comment: Why not create a new file and delete the old one (you could generate a file name with a time stamp for example on the end)? I'd image it's cached/copied as you suspect.

Comment: ok this with the cache was a theory. Is there really a cache for lock screen images? Will try this with time stamp